# How to close executereader in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using more then one repeater on same page. But when I use Execute reader for 2nd repeater then it gives exception that there is already execute reader running.. so close it. I put `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` but it give error that command behaviour doesn't exists... Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to bind the repeaters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly close the `DataReader` if you specify that `CommandBehavior`, it will not do it for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would bind UI controls to strongly typed objects. So for example I would define a Product model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then a method to read products from the database:

```
public static IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Some connection string"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT prod_id, prod_name FROM products";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new Product
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("prod_id")),
                    Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("prod_name")),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the web tier I would call this method to fetch my products and bind them to some UI controls:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var products = Db.GetProducts().ToArray();

    repeater1.DataSource = products;
    repeater2.DataSource = products;
    gridView.DataSource = products;
    ...
}
```

And when you get sick of writing those SQL queries you might take a look at an ORM, such as [Entity Framework](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) for example.

Comment: Before choosing an ORM, in particular EF, consider evaluting all the pros and cons. Check [link](http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/)